# NERDTree does not open in the directory from which macvim was opened

Tags: macvim, nerdtree

I upgraded my macvim to 7.3 recently and I can no longer open nerdtree or netw in the directory in which macvim was opened, it always opens in my home directory.

For example,

If I open macvim in /users/me/test/project dir, I want the NERDTree root to be /Users/me/test/project and not /Users/me.

Any ideas?

Comment: I reverted back to macvim 7.2 and I don't have the issue anymore.

Comment: How are you opening MacVim? Using the latest `mvim` command this works fine for me in 7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this

(all changes in .vimrc)

1. Enabled NERDTree as default.

   ```
   autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
   ```
2. Put [this](https://gist.github.com/800687) script I got from github in .vimrc. This will make vim AND NERDTree buffer quit with `:q`
3. Say, your project folder is /home/user/my-project, then do this:

   ```
   mvim /home/user/my-project/README
   ```

   You wil get the parent folder in the NERDTree with the files in it.

Answer (score 2):

You could map the key you use to open NERDTree like this(in .vimrc):

```
map <silent> <F1> :NERDTreeToggle %:p:h<CR>
```

This maps my F1 key to toggle(open/close) NERDTree using the path of the currently active buffer. If no buffer is open, it opens in the currently launched Macvim directory.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem after upgrading janus.  simply adding this to my .gvimrc fixed it:

```
set autochdir
```

This will set the working directory to the current file.

More info here:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file

Answer (score 0):

This problem (if it is the one I think it is) was fixed in [Snapshot 55](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/ChangeLog), so a simple update should fix it.